# What is the correct way of passing a resource link to an entity constructor as parameter?

Tags: spring-data-rest

When a resource is being posted, is it possible to use the resource's entity constructor instead of a repository event handler to run logic on the posted relationships? If so, how? I am looking for the case where the related resource already exists but only the relationship is being created with the newly created resource.